# Word 2017, How to Create a Book from individual Chapter Files

Tags: microsoft-word, chapters

Back in 2005 I finished my Masters thesis. For that thesis, each chapter was it's own file. The master document was essentially an outline where each chapter was a link to an external Word file.

With all the data and equations in each chapter this was an absolute life saver. I could work on a chapter without the 15 min loading and the constant bogging down of having to re-paginate every time I typed 3 words.

Anytime I wanted to see the whole doc at once I could load up the master doc. Obviously, I had to do this for the final draft.

That was then, 12 yrs later I don't remember how I did it and it probably wouldn't matter if I could given the UI changes since then.

All my Googling led to people suggesting that you insert Object as Text... But then the formatting gets screwed up. I haven't yet tested it but it appears to be static rather than a link.

Does anyone know how to do this in Word today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the Master Document functionality, on the **View** tab, in the **Views** group, click **Outline**. You're taken to a new tab that's named **Outlining**. In the **Master Document** group, click **Show Document**. You can then click **Insert** to insert subdocuments into the current document, which then becomes the master document.

You can also use **Object** > **Insert as Text** in the **Text** group on the **Insert** tab. The trick is that, after you select a file to insert, you have to click the arrow on the right side of the **Insert** button and then click **Insert as Link**. Otherwise, as you noted, the subdocument is inserted as static text.